# Singleton config - how to avoid returning a Promise in typescript

Tags: javascript

I have my Configuration class:

```
interface ConfigObject {
  apiUrl: string;
  identityPoolId: string;
  identityPoolRegion: string;
  region: string;
  userPoolId: string;
  userPoolWebClientId: string;
}

class Configuration {
  private static _instance: ConfigObject;

  public static get Instance() {
    return (
      this._instance ||
      this.getConfig<ConfigObject>().then((config) => {
        this._instance = config;
        return config;
      })
    );
  }

  private static async getConfig<TConfig>(): Promise<TConfig> {
    const response = await fetch('env.json', {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
      },
    });
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(response.statusText);
    }
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
  }
}

export default Configuration.Instance;
```

and I want to access it's values in my service:

```
export default class APIService {
  static baseURL: string = `${Config.apiUrl}/mocked`;
```

Yet at the time of accessing `Config.apiUrl` is `undefined`

How can I make sure that the getConfig fetch gets executed and the actual object is returned instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make an asynchronous process synchronous. But you *can* make your module wait to load until you've read that JSON file, by using [top-level `await`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await), which is now broadly supported in browsers and by bundlers.

```
async function getConfigData(): Promise<ConfigObject> {
    const response = await fetch('env.json', {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
      },
    });
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(response.statusText);
    }
    const data: ConfigObject = await response.json();
    return data;
}
const data = await getConfigData(); // *** Module load waits here

class Configuration {
    private static _instance: ConfigObject;

    public static get Instance() {
        if (!this._instance) {
            this._instance = data;
        }
        return this._instance;
    }
}

export default Configuration.Instance;
```

That said, there doesn't seem to be any purpose to the `Configuration` class, just export the data directly:

```
async function getConfigData(): Promise<ConfigObject> {
    const response = await fetch('env.json', {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
      },
    });
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(response.statusText);
    }
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
}
const data: ConfigObject = await getConfigData(); // *** Module load waits here

export default data;
```

---

Side note: Since objects are mutable by default, any module that imports the configuration data can modify it (for instance, if there's a `data.example` property, by doing `data.example = "some value"`). Maybe you want it to be mutable, in which case don't do anything, but if you don't you might use [`Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) to make everything about the object read-only:

```
// ...
const data: ConfigObject = await getConfigData();
Object.freeze(data); // *** Freezes the object

export default data;
```